# How to create a batch file that will run cmd and a exe with parameters

Tags: windows, command-line

How to create a batch file that do following:
For example program name is `hi.exe` will do the following:

1. Run `hi.exe` in cmd with arguments `hi.exe -f%l%`.
2. Instead of `%1%` I want user to input the number of his choice.

Answer (score 3):

1) You do not need to open a cmd window separately. You can use `start` command followed by path of exe. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221730/bat-file-to-run-a-exe-at-the-command-prompt

2) To read arguments you can use a statement like: `set /p name= What is your name?` which prompts user with question "What is your name?" and accepts the input in variable 'p'.
Check here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223721/in-windows-cmd-how-do-i-prompt-for-user-input-and-use-the-result-in-another-com